# Use DNS A-Record to forward traffic to a third server

Tags: dns, a-records

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I'm stuck in a bind and can't seem to find a solution. The scenerio:

- Client has set up subdomain.example.com which lists an A record at the domain registrar to point the hosting for the subdomain to server B (using IP)
- the subdomain now needs to be moved to server C for better resources, but we can't change the IP address at the domain registrar (in-house IT team won't give access or make the change!)
- I thought maybe I could setup an A record at server B that points to server C, but that didn't seem to work.

Is there a way to have server B send traffic to server C, using the same URL? (subdomain.example.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

DNS is hierarchical. If whoever controls the domain (or an ancestor) refuses to help you, you're out of luck. Get a new domain, or a new in-house IT team.